# Is this making an ArrayBuffer sorted?

Tags: scala

I have a simple question about using ArrayBuffer in Scala

```
    class NewArray[A <% OtherClass with Ordered[A]] (arrb: ArrayBuffer[Long]) {
        val arrBuffer: ArrayBuffer[Long] = arrb

        def +(n : Long) {
        if(!this.isMember(n))
          arrBuffer += n
        }
        ...
    }
```

NewArray encapsulates a arrBuffer of type ArrayBuffer. New operations performed on NewArray is essentially based on ArrayBuffer.

Is the NewArray sorted? How to do a sorted array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's obviously lots of code missing, but `ArrayBuffer` does not sort things added to it, nor does it provide an in-place sort.  If you need something to stay sorted after every insert, a tree is the way to go, but Scala doesn't provide a mutable tree.  Use `java.util.TreeSet` as your internal representation.

There may be better options than this, but it's hard to tell from what you've said.

If you are asking whether adding `[A <% OtherClass with Ordered[A]]` will make your `Long` array sorted, no, not at all.  That simply says that you had better be able to think of some orderable class when you create a new array.  But if you don't use that class, knowing about it does precisely nothing!

Answer (score 1):

If you are wrapping an ArrayBuffer of `A`s (not sure what you are doing with the `Long`s), then you will be able to sort the buffer using `arrb.sorted`.